# Word for a "Male Mistress"

Tags: synonyms, slang, formality

Is the male version of a mistress, a mastress? It's a term I would use, but I don't know if it is just slang or if it is formal...

P.S.  I mean a male that sleeps with a married woman (love, not business)

Comment: Fancy man:(UK) A woman's lover.

Comment: Does there have to be one? 'Fancy man'is the term I would use.

Comment: Definitely a UK term. I've never heard of it before (in the USA)

Comment: I like mastress. If a mistress is what comes(!) between a mister and his mattress, surely it works the other way too!

Comment: My word association when thinking of the word "mastress" is a mattress in BDSM gear. I think I like "mastress" for different reasons than you, Mynamite.

Comment: Extra-curricular consort?

Comment: @BlessedGeek, consort is gender-neutral, though I must admit I usually see it used for males.

Comment: Is a gigolo pronounced jigolo or gi golo? Because it makes a difference whether they jiggle or giggle while on the job.

Comment: I agree with Josh61: "fancy man" is exactly and unambiguously the (somewhat slang) term for it in British English.

Comment: the male version of *mistress* is *master*.

Comment: Why not 'a toy boy'....?

Comment: @WS2 A toy boy is specifically a younger man with an older woman.

Comment: That's not what [fancy man](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fancy-man) means. It refers to any unmarried male lover.

Answer (score 7):

Personally, I would call such an unofficial sexual partner *a lover*, no matter what the genders of the people involved. The online Merriam-Webster's dictionary's [definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lover) of *lover* includes the following meaning:

> someone with whom a married person is having a love affair

So, while the word does not necessarily imply a man sleeping with a married woman, it most certainly can be used that way.

---

If you're looking for a disparaging term, you could use *boy toy*, defined by [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/boy-toy) as:

> Also, toy boy. a young man noted for his good looks and sexual prowess, especially one who maintains relationships with older, more powerful persons.

Answer (score 4):

That would definitely be slang (slang that ignores the fact that words ending in -ess usually denote something feminine, for that matter). "Paramour" is more unisex and means something similar, though.

Answer (score 2):

As J.A. said, "paramour" is a gender-neutral equivalent, and a good way to express a "male mistress", so long as there is a some gender-context provided for the reader/listener. But the question specifically asked for a male-equivalent, not a male-acceptable equivalent.

Technically, **[Cicisbeo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cicisbeo)** is the word you are looking for. However, I had not even heard of the term before today. It could be a product of merely ignorance, or its lack of prevalence in the USA. I won't speculate.

Comment: As I understand it, a *cicisbeo* was a lover in the romantic sense, but explicitly not in the physical sense.

Comment: Interesting. As I had never seen its use before, I had only the Wikipedia article to reference. What context have you seen it used in, and where?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict the connotation of mistress to a kept lover, then gigilo would be appropriate as a male equivalent.

Comment: A) OP specifically says "love, not business" and B) *gigolo* would be better.