# What is the opposite of mistress?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

Normally, we say

> "He was caught with his mistress."

Here, we know that the male is a married person. The meaning is clear.

If he is not married, then we can say

> "He was caught with his girlfriend."

But, how to convey that a **married female** was caught with her *lover*.

> a female was caught with her ____.

Saying that, *she was caught with her boyfriend* does not clear the air that she is married or not.

So, is there any male-gender specific word opposite of mistress and clears the air that female is cheating her husband?

I googled few words: 
lover, sweetheart, loved one, love, beloved, darling, dearest, young man, man friend, man, escort, wooer, admirer etc.

And, from Wikipedia,

> "Paramour" is sometimes used, but this term can apply to either partner in an illicit relationship, so it is not exclusively male.

But, none fits the requirement.

Comment: There isn't one. It's sort of implied if you say *lover*, especially if you have just said *caught*, which tells us you think she was doing something wrong. Otherwise you either spell out the fact that she is married to someone else or say something like *was caught cheating on her husband*.

Comment: @Minty my father caught me with my lover? Does it says, that I am married or not?

Comment: Also, why in the history we never required such a word?

Comment: No - it implies that you were doing something wrong, but since you mention your father I'd say the inference is that you are too young to have a lover, not that you are already committed to someone else.

Comment: The focus is on the husband in both cases - an example of how gendered language can be perhaps. If you think about words like *mistress* or *madam* and the male counterparts *master* and *sir*, there's quite a difference in usage...

Comment: @Minty that is really bad.

Comment: Despite what some dictionaries say, _mistress_ does not imply marriage either. It just implies that the guy has a significant other that he is cheating on (or, alternatively, that he is in a BDSM relationship, in which case _mistress_ retains its original meaning of ‘female master’). It may just be a girlfriend. I am not aware of any word, for males or females, that specifically means ‘the third party in an extramarital affair’, but I’m not aware of any male equivalent to _mistress_ in this sense either.

Comment: I would say "master" and let people puzzle over the meaning.

Comment: See also https://english.stackexchange.com/q/206702/191178

Comment: In former times when premarital sex was officially frowned upon, a single man could equally well be referred to as having a mistress. The counterpart would be 'lover'.

Comment: 'Paramour' is extremely outdated/purple prose. 'Lover' is more recent (60's) but is a bit cringeworthy. Nowadays, I feel like a noun wouldn't be used at all (for either gender), just something like 'they're seeing someone else' or they're having an affair'

Comment: It is interested to see that without looking into definition of paramour you all marked it as a duplicate. Paramour is a gender neutral word. I already stated in my description. Instead, I would prefer that you say me "there are no such word in English language".

Answer (score 1):

Rather like *mistress* can refer to women connected to unmarried people but usually refers to a woman with a married man, the **[other man](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/other%20man)** usually refers to a man with a married woman.

The Oxford English Dictionary gives this definition and these examples:

> **[other man](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/133219#eid33050636)**  n. the lover of a married woman or female partner.
>
> 1886   R. Kipling Other Man in Civil & Mil. Gaz. 13 Nov. 3/3   They married her when she..had given all her poor little heart to another man... We will call him the Other Man.
>
> 1966   ‘S. Ransome’ Hidden Hour ii. 20   She had been here before. With the ‘other man’?
>
> 1994   Sunday Times 6 Mar. (Style & Travel section) viii. 4/1   He was cited by the Tory MP..as ‘the other man’ when he sued his wife..for divorce.

Other examples abound. There is the 2008 film *[The Other Man](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0974613/)*, in which a husband finds out about the *other man* in his now-deceased wife's life. (Side note: it's a bad movie.)

A recent popular romance novel called *[The Other Man](https://books.google.com/books?id=OdpwDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22the%20other%20man%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiz0b7S7ejhAhXLmeAKHcbsCowQ6AEIOzAD#v=onepage&q=%22the%20other%20man%22&f=false)* has this on its first page:

> For every hotwife and her husband, there's always the other man.

It definitely refers to a male partner from outside the relationship. In most usage, that relationship is a marriage.

Finally, what I particularly like about this phrasing is that its gender counterpart is so simple: **[the other woman](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/other%20woman)**.

Comment: I can't open the link. Can you please upload the screen shot of OED?

Comment: @Oxi What do you need from the screenshot that you can't get from the quote?

Comment: Secondly, question is marked duplicate and the answer of the linked question is not correct. It has only created confusion now.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>*Not an officially-sourced answer.*</sup>

No time like the present to start breaking down gendered bias. You could use the word **mistress**.